# Как посчитать промежуток времени?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть датафрейм `df`:

| Header | Start time | End time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 | 02/Aug/21 11:42 PM | 08/Aug/21 2:55 PM |
| Task 2 | 30/Jul/21 10:02 PM | 12/Aug/21 9:03 PM |

Пытаюсь понять, как вычислить, сколько времени ушло на `Task1` и `Task2`.

Подскажите, какие шаги нужно предпринять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["diff"] = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains("time$")].apply(pd.to_datetime).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

результат:

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
   Header          Start time           End time             diff
0  Task 1  02/Aug/21 11:42 PM  08/Aug/21 2:55 PM  5 days 15:13:00
1  Task 2  30/Jul/21 10:02 PM  12/Aug/21 9:03 PM 12 days 23:01:00
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds", и, кажется, это потому, что не везде в моем полном df в End time есть значение (где-то таски не закрыты и стоит NaN). 
А есть возможность посчитать количество дней в случае, если таск еще не закрыт? Например: 
|Task 3    | 30/Jul/21 10:02 PM     |     NaN    |

Comment: @Helga вы тогда приведите в впросе пример со всеми возможными вариантами (включая незакрытые задачи). Есть возможность все посчитать, если во время подсчета вместо nan поставить текущие дату и время.

Comment: @strawdog, это выяснилось в ходе исполнения предложенного кода. Спасибо за идею!

Comment: такой код вроде тоже рабочий: `df["diff"] = pd.to_datetime(df['End time'])-pd.to_datetime(df['Start time'])`

Comment: @SergFSM, да, работает! Спасибо! И на моем уровне владения питоном он очень понятен и полезен, спасибо еще раз!